# Function to print out a 2d array returning address values in C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a function that prints an array that I pass into it. However, the console outputs the following instead of the values I specify.

00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C 00B4F91C

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< typename T, size_t N, size_t M >
void printm(T (&matrix1)[N][M] ) {
    for (double i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (double j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            cout << matrix1 << " ";

        }
    }
}

int main() {

    double M[3][3] = { {0.36, 0.48, -0.8} , {-0.8, 0.6, 0.0} , {0.48, 0.64, 0.6} };
    printm(M);

}
```

Comment: Why an object of the type double is used as an index? Also you mean  cout << matrix1[i][j] << " ";

Comment: not sure how you expected it to print values when you weren't using `i` or `j` at all

Comment: I tried this earlier and it produces an error.

Comment: Hi everyone. The issue is fixed now. It was mostly due to the fact that I labelled i and j as doubles when they should be integers.

Comment: [Just fyi, worth a look](https://ideone.com/FhrZId).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be outputting the values at the indices in the loop

```
cout << matrix1[i][j] << " ";
```

Your indices should also be integral types

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, it gives an error. "subscript is not of integral type"

Comment: @43zombiegit Correct you cannot use a `double` to index into an array, it should be a (preferably unsigned) integer

Answer (score 0):

You are printing matrix1...

```
cout << matrix1 << " ";
```

You should print matrix1[ i ][ j ]..

```
cout << matrix1[ i ][ j ] << " ";
```